# Printing a grid with labels, and Both Axis start bottom left

Tags: python

I'm trying to print a grid where the X & Y axis start at the bottom right with column and Row numbers
The Code below outputs something like this (numbers for illustration)

So the X axis is correct but the Y axis needs to start at the bottom and go up

```
  1           4
|___|___|___|___|     1
|___|___|___|___|
|___|_X_|_X_|_X_|
|___|_X_|_X_|___|
|___|___|_X_|___|
|___|___|_X_|___|     6
```

What I'd like is something like this

```
   |___|___|___|___|___
06 |___|___|_X_|___|___
05 |___|___|_X_|___|___
04 |___|_X_|_X_|___|___
03 |___|_X_|_X_|_X_|___
02 |___|___|___|___|___
01 |___|___|___|___|___
    01   02  03  04

# Sample coords 
coords = [(3, 6), (3, 5), (3, 4), (2, 4), (2, 3), (3, 3), (3, 4), ...]
def make_grid():
    return [['___' for dummy_col in range(13,0 ,-1)] for dummy_row in range(13)]


def place_on_grid(grid, x, y):
    grid[x][y] = '_X_'

def repr_grid(grid):
    return '\n'.join('|' + '|'.join(sub + ['']) for sub in grid)


def place_items_on_grid(coords):
    grid = make_grid()
    for x, y in coords:
        place_on_grid(grid, x,y)
    print(repr_grid(grid))


place_items_on_grid(coords)
```

I thought `range(13,0 ,-1)` would work for the Y axis but it didn't make any difference nor did `reversed(range(13))`.

**UPDATE:** print function from @wiii comments Isn't working

```
def repr_grid(grid):
    pgrid =''
    y=12
    for row in grid:
        row = f'\n{y:02}'.join('|' +  row[0])
        pgrid += row
        y-=1
    pgrid += "\n___|01_|02_|03_|04_|05_|06_|07_|08_|09_|10_|11_|12_|___"
    return pgrid
```

Comment: Your `range(13)` just creates the empty cells, so of course it does not matter in which order you draw them.

Comment: When you replace an empty cell by an 'X' that's where you need to count the rows from the bottom instead of from the top.

Comment: Are you suggesting manipulating the Y values? if Y== 10: Y= 2 ?

Comment: If not can you show me?